Run sturtup script as root on Gentoo/KDE
There is an issue of automounting a partition after unexpected shutdown.
The startup script checks if ntfs partition is mounted and mounts it if not.
if grep -qs '/MountedDisk' /proc/mounts; 
    then echo "MountedDisk is mounted."; 
else
    echo -e "MountedDisk is not mounted. \n Checking the partition and mounting it..."
    ntfsfix --clear-dirty /dev/sdc1;
    mount -t ntfs3 /dev/sdc1 /MountedDisk/;
fi

The file with that script is placed in /home/Username/.config/autostart/ and on Plasma6 startup settings set to executable.
However, it can only be ran as root -- how to make it run with root rights?

I believe /proc/mounts is what's causing the issue.  Can /MountedDisk be checked for empty and then mounted?

I think we can check for empty but we need the root privilege to mount it (and for ntfsfix) anyway

The easiest fix for this is to check if the user is root before running the script. The other way would be sudo.

why not put it into root's cron table with a schedule of @reboot?

@eyoung100 and how to do it with sudo?

Installing Sudo on Gentoo
I'm adding this answer per the comment as the OP asked.  Doing this will turn your Gentoo install into a Debian/Ubuntu like system as both Debian and Ubuntu use sudo in place of the actual root account to increase system security.

emerge -av app-admin/sudo
su -
EDITOR="/bin/nano" visudo
Find the following:

    ##
    ## User privilege specification
    ##
    root ALL=(ALL) ALL

    ## Uncomment to allow members of group wheel to execute any command
    # %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL

    ## Same thing without a password
    # %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

    ## Uncomment to allow members of group sudo to execute any command
    # %sudo   ALL=(ALL) ALL

The post-install hook for emerge creates the wheel group as the default so uncomment a line above starting with %wheel. My personal preference is to choose Execute any command WITH A PASSWORD, but either will work.
As a final stap we now need to add our user to the wheel group with: useradd -aG wheel codegust where codegust is assumed to be your username. See Also: Gentoo Wiki: Sudo

Thank you! That is a great answer. Still, I am not sure I wish to risk to bring those changes into my system. There are sudo and wheel groups in it already. Basically, I hoped I just can mark somehow that script of mine as root/sudo-privileged so that it can execute on login.

Is sudo already installed on your system?

Yes. My user us in sudo group.

Then sudo bash /path/to/script.sh would work just fine.  The only way you can grant root privileges at startup is as a cron job.  See @DopeGhoti's comment in your post above.

Also to the question of "marking a script as [...] privileged", there is the suid bit which can be set upon executable files, but I believe that is not respected on shell scripts; only for binaries.  If though your script can be run through sudo, and you can do so without needing ti interactively provide your password, you can have a cron table entry of @reboot sudo /path/to/myscript.sh for the user you wish to invoke the script as.
